# Rules about ContentController or Page_Controlle in Silverstripe

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

What are the rules regarding the use of ContentController vs Page_Controller classes in Silverstripe? When do you one instead of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you extend `Page` as new pagetype, you should use `Page_Controller` as controller extension. This allows you to add "global" methods for templates inside `Page_Controller`.

`ContentController` is just a base class for page controllers that handles internal logic specific to pages, as opposed to `DataObjects`. You don't use it directly usually.

Comment: Greg can you point me to link where there is a good explanation of getresponse() and setresponse() in action with controllers? Thanks as always. The https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/controllers/introduction/ is not too thorough.

Comment: First of all you should understand [Execution pipeline](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/execution_pipeline/). Then check api documentation for `SS_HTTPRequest` and `SS_HTTPResponse`.